# Is it possible to run two commands at the same time in a shell script?

Tags: bash, background-process, parallelism

I know that on the command line I can use `&` to run a command in the background. But I'm wondering if I can do it in a script.

I have a script like this:

```
date_stamp=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d" --date='yesterday')
shopt -s extglob

cd /my/working/directory/

sh ./stay/get_it_ios.sh
sh ./stay/get_it_mix.sh

cd stay
zip  ../stay_$date_stamp.zip  ./*201*

rm ./stay/!(*py|*sh)
```

And I want to run `sh ./stay/get_it_ios.sh` and `sh ./stay/get_it_mix.sh` together to get more accurate data. Is it possible to do this in the scope of a shell script?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, it is.  If you want to do two things concurrently, and wait for them both to complete, you can do something like:

```
sh ./stay/get_it_ios.sh &  PIDIOS=$!
sh ./stay/get_it_mix.sh &  PIDMIX=$!
wait $PIDIOS
wait $PIDMIX
```

Your script will then run both scripts in parallel, and wait for both scripts to complete before continuing.

Comment: You can just run one `wait` without argument to wait for both processes.

Comment: Unless earlier in the script, you'd backgrounded a third process that is supposed to run through to a later point.  Better to affirmatively declare what you are `wait`ing for, in my opinion.

Comment: When you say *run both scripts in parallel* do you mean that they will start at the same time? I mean, suppose that we were able to register the time with very huge precision (for example, using atomic clocks). Both should start together? I ask because the scripts reads line by line, right?

Comment: As you surmise, the scripts won't begin execution at the same instant down to the clock cycle.  Shell scripts run the commands in the order they are given, so the first backgrounded command will run before the second if only (in nearly all cases) _very_ slightly.  When I say they will "run in parallel", I mean exactly that: both will _run_ concurrently (subject to job management, signal handling, and/or kernel prioritization).