# Two commands to run simultaneously in two terminals

Tags: linux, terminal

I have to run script in one Terminal (Server) and jar file in Second Terminal (User) at same time and millisec matters. Is it Possible. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to run two commands at the same time in a shell script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162645/is-it-possible-to-run-two-commands-at-the-same-time-in-a-shell-script)

Comment: @Tejas no it's not. This question is about running commands in 2 separate terminals, not one.

Comment: How important is it for the commands to be run **exactly** at the same time?  Would a 1ms delay be too much for example?  Do you need to command to actually run in each corresponding shell or do you just need the output in those 2 terminals?

Comment: Use two different computers to connect and press "Enter" on both keyboards at the same time.  This isn't a very specific question, is it?

Comment: I have to run script in one Terminal (Server) and jar file in Second Terminal (User) at same time and millisec also matters

Answer (score 6):

You can use file locks to accomplish this fairly easily.

Create 2 scripts with the following contents. Run the terminal A script first, then B.

Terminal A:

```
touch /tmp/lockfile
flock -x /tmp/lockfile read -p 'press enter to begin'
command_a
```

Terminal B:

```
flock -x /tmp/lockfile true
command_b
```

Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> in terminal A when you are ready to begin.

The way it works is that the first `flock` grabs an exclusive lock on `/tmp/lockfile`, and holds that lock until you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
The second `flock` also attempts to grab an exclusive lock, but is blocked because the lock is already held. As soon as the first `flock` releases the lock, the second one runs `/bin/true`, which immediately returns, and so the commands continue.

Yes, this means that `command_a` will start a tiny fraction of a second before `command_b`. But in shell scripting, such delays are going to be unavoidable anyway, so it shouldn't matter.

*Depending on your linux flavor, you might not have `/bin/read`. You can accomplish the same by doing `flock ... bash -c "read -p 'press enter to begin'"`*

Comment: I'd do `tmux new-window command_a & tmux new-window command_b` but I'm not sure whether that's overkill or this answer is underkill.

Comment: And if there's a `/bin/read`, it's likely it won't support a `-p` option as that's specific to the `bash` builtin (other shells like `ksh` or `zsh` use `read 'var?prompt'` instead). You may want to use `head -n 1 > /dev/null` or `line > /dev/null` instead. (and issue the prompt with `printf` beforehand).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a named pipe. An `open()` in *read* mode on a named pipe blocks until another `open()` is made in *write* mode (and vice versa).

Create the pipe first with:

```
mkfifo mypipe
```

Then:

- First terminal:

  ```
  cmd1 3> mypipe 3>&-
  ```
- Second terminal:

  ```
  cmd2 3< mypipe 3<&-
  ```

The `open()` done by the first shell on `mypipe` before executing `cmd1` will unblock as soon as  the second shell opens `mypipe`. Note that the two *processes* will be started at different times, but the two *commands* will be executed at the same time as that's what those two processes will do just after opening the pipe.

If you wanted to start both *processes* at the same time, you could do:

- `:>mypipe; cmd1`
- `:<mypipe; cmd2`

Though that would make it slightly less likely that both *commands* be executed at the same time (as both shells may take different amounts of time to start the processes).